# Next Auh Giving Cannot GET /api/auth/error in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am using "next-auth": "^4.22.1","react": "^17.0.2" and "next": "^12.2.5".
I used Next-auh for google and facebook authentication at sign up and login. Everything is working good in development but in production on signIn() its giving following statement
"{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /api/auth/error","error":"Not Found"}"

Following is [...nextauth].js and .env files

[...nextauth].js

```
`import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import {useCustomContext} from"../../../components/customcontext";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId:process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',

});
 `
```

.env

```
`GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

NEXTAUTH_URL=https://mysite.io/
# NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3001/
NEXTAUTH_SECRET = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
SECRET= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`
```

Google OAuth Cliet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F51rH.png)

Facebook> settings> basic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtDIM.png)

Facebook> products> configure> settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybgT9.png)

I did see a few solutions on the internet but nothing helped. There were solution regarding correct NEXTAUTH_URL and NEXTAUTH_SECRET, the url is correct in google and facbook console and as for NEXTAUTH_SECRET, did try different options including openssl rand -base64 32 but nothing helped. at the end even tried putting SECRET value directly in [...nextauth].js